# Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking

Tags: supervisord

My `supervisord` told me that it is running without any HTTP authentication checking.

```
supervisor> maintail
2015-03-03 16:57:03,832 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
```

Although I cannot open it on the default port `9001`.
How to open it and how to enable HTTP authentication checking?

`unix_http_server` config file part is the following:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock
chmod=0770
chown=root:supervisor
```

Comment: firewall? netstat -punta?

Comment: @lVlint67 there is no firewall, just iptables, but they do not affect the port `9001`. `netstat -punta` gives a lot of rows, none of them has the port `9001`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the HTTP server to listen on a TCP port (instead of a Unix domain socket), then you need to use `inet_http_server` instead of `unix_http_server`.

Documentation: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#inet-http-server-section-settings

Comment: It would have been nice to add a little "color" to the answer.  For us supervisor newbs, why is this a critical error?  What is HTTP authentication checking and why is it preferable?

Comment: @Robert EXACTLY! Please see https://serversforhackers.com/monitoring-processes-with-supervisord

Comment: And when you change the type of listener, be aware that you have to also tell supervisorctl which one you're using!  http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisorctl-section-settings

Answer (score 7):

You got

> CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking

is because username/password is not set for supervisor's unix http server.

Add them into `supervisord.conf`'s `[unix_http_server]`:

```
[unix_http_server]
username = dummy
password = dummy
```

But you will be asked for username/password when you use `supervisorctl`.
Add same items into `[supervisorctl]` and you are good to go.

```
[supervisorctl]
username = dummy
password = dummy
```

More info: 
([#694](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/694))
([#717](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/717))